# How to link to Routes inside the component rendered by another Route with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm trying to use react router in my reactjs app. And I encountered this problem:

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import About from '../Pages/About';
import Home from '../Pages/Home';
import Topics from '../Pages/Topics';
import LinkTest from '../Pages/LinkTest';

class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
              </li>
              <Route path="/home" component={LinkTest}/>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />

          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Ignore "about" and "topic" component, when I click on "Home" link, it should target 2 routes, one will render "LinkTest" and the other renders "Home".

This is what inside "LinkTest":

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class LinkTest extends Component {
  render() {
      const {match}=this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/Test`}>Link To Test</Link>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LinkTest;
```

And inside my "Home" component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Test from './Test';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
      const {match} = this.props;
      console.log(match.url);
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Hello from Home page
                    <Link to={`${match.url}/Test`}>Link To Test</Link>
                    <Route path={`${match.url}/Test`} component={Test}/>
                </h2>

            </div>
        </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

However:

- When i click on the link inside "LinkTest" component (which was rendered earlier), the url on the browser is shown "http://localhost:3000/home/Test", but nothing happens.
- When i clicked on the link inside "Home" component, (which was rendered the same time as the "LinkTest" using the same link), it showed the same url on the browser: "http://localhost:3000/home/Test", only this time it rendered the "Test" component.

Why does this happen? (what i want to achieve is I want to use the link inside "LinkTest" to render "Test" component inside "Home" component, or something similar).

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and your code is way too messy. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), come back and add more code (especially your `index.js` and `App.js` file) and a better explanation of your problem, or at least what EXACTLY you want to achieve.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Yes, you did and now it looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in following way:

```
<Route exact path='/a' component={A} />
<Route path='/b' component={B} />

// Following should be router inside Component B
<Route exact path='/b/abc' component={OtherComponent}
```

If you want I've prepared few react-router 4 examples. These are hosted here. https://github.com/SandipNirmal/react-router-examples

Comment: I have edited the problem so as to make it clearer of what i meant

Answer (score 1):

If you need **Nested routing** inside `ComponentB` you should add `Link`s for those `Route`s as well. And use `match.url` and `match.path` to build the nested `Link`s and `Route`s.

```
const ComponentB = ({ match }) => {
    return (
        <div> 
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/c`}>Component C</Link></li>

                    // more Links
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/css`}>CSS</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/react`}>React</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Route path={`${match.path}/c`} component={ComponentC} />

                // more nested Routes
                <Route path={`${match.path}/css`} render={() => { return <h1>CSS</h1> }}/>
                <Route path={`${match.path}/react`} render={() => { return <h1>React</h1> }}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

### Nested routing

Components created via **Route** will automatically be passed the following `prop` objects: `match`, `location` and `history`.

Using `match` you can implement nested `Route`s. The `match` object contains the following properties:

- `params` — (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding
  to the dynamic segments of the path
- `isExact` — (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
- `path` — **(string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested `Route`s**
- `url` — **(string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building
  nested `Link`s**

---

### Reference

1. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/beginners-guide-to-react-router-4-8959ceb3ad58
2. https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf